# JSP - Subtracting value from database

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I am attempting to create a orders system in JSP & MySQL, I was hoping someone could please help me.

I want to be able to decrease the stock level of a product when it is placed in a order. 
(ie.  9* 16gb USB Flash Drives are purchased. At the time the order is placed A SQL query retrieves the current level 50 and subtracts the ordered amount 9 and updates the database with the new level 41).

I have tried this JSP but I can not get it to work.

```
<sql:query var="stockresult" scope="request" dataSource="jdbc/project">
  SELECT *
  FROM stocklevels
  WHERE productID = $param.productID
</sql:query>

$newstocklevel = stockresult - $orderqty;


<sql:update var="newstock" scope="request" dataSource="jdbc/project">
  UPDATE stocklevels
  SET stock=$newstocklevel
  WHERE productID = $param.productID
</sql:update>
```

Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Have never written SQLs in JSP code before but I believe the update needs to be in the sql:update tag!

Comment: You really shouldn't do that in a jsp.

Comment: @sarego yup sorry I do know that, I just forgot to copy the whole thing in, working between 2 computer sometimes you forget things!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yeh I know I should have used PHP but when I began the project I was not familiar with PHP. Any help.

Comment: @bil that's not what SotiriosDelimanolis was saying. He meant that you're breaking the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Knowing this, your business logic should be in a server side component like a Servlet. And for the PHP way to handle this, saying *I should have used this language instead of another* just shows that you're not prepared for programming.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ahh okey I see. Thanks for your advice. Maybe I am not prepared for programming, or it could show that now that I have used PHP I am leaning towards it, (but its a little to late to change my project to it?) anyhow practice makes you better, btw I have been programming for about  4 years now :)

Comment: @bil don't take it as offense, but I've seen people who has worked on programming for more than 10 years and still aren't good programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a solution for you, but it is highly recommended not to insert request parameters directly in an SQL statement.

```
<sql:query var="stockresult" scope="request" dataSource="jdbc/project">
   SELECT stock <!-- select the current stock -->
   FROM stocklevels
   WHERE productID = $param.productID
</sql:query>

<!-- calculate the new value from the first row of the query result -->
<c:set var"newstocklevel" value="${stockresult.rows[0].stock - orderqty}"/> 


<sql:update var="newstock" scope="request" dataSource="jdbc/project">
   UPDATE stocklevels
   SET stock=$newstocklevel
   WHERE productID = $param.productID
</sql:query>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @rusty. I will try this out when I get back on to my development computer at home.

You are right about parameters direct in SQL. I usually use productID=? and then use <sql:param value = "${param.productID}" /> but I used the direct way just to see if I could get it working.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help once again, it did not work :( I tried changing the value="${stockresult.rows[0].stock} - {$orderqty}" to value="${orderqty}" and the stock updated to qty in orderform but the math in the doesn't work, I just end up with stock as 0.
Any ideas? please

Comment: Did you try this?: value = "${stockresult.rows[0].stock - orderqty}"

Comment: OMG! I can not believe I did not try that, dumb dumb me!. Thank you very much @rusty. I been trying to set so many different variables and failing when it was so in my face, I knew it was because of the ${ } but never thought of combining the 2.

Comment: Your welcome @bil. I edited my answer, so it has the correct answer now.